# JavaScript Draggable Library for Inline Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

All of the well established JavaScript libraries for controlling the dragging and dropping and elements (e.g. jQuery UI Draggable) focus on dragging non-online elements (by setting their top/left position style attributes.

This is fine in some circumstances, but I am creating a WYSIWYG editor where users can insert images into paragraphs as inline elements. I would like to be able to make the dragging of these elements work better - but a lot of the features of the ondrag and related events don't work cross-platform.

Is there a library out there that allows us to have nice dragging of inline elements (like images) inside paragraphs which are inside of a contenteditable container?

Comment: I would suggest jQuery UI. It's really hard to advise without seeing what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hi @Twisty - the problem with jQuery UI is that it doesn't really work with elements that are meant to be inline inside of a paragraph - it is very focused on block elements.